# Return dictionary with one changed element

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> d = [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]
```

And I want to perform a map operation where I change just one value in each dictionary. One possible way to do that is to create a new dictionary which simply contains the original values along with the changed ones:

```
>>> map(lambda x: {'a': x['a'], 'b': x['b'] + 1, 'c': x['c']}, d)
[{'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'c': 7, 'b': 7}]
```

This can get unruly if the dictionaries have many items.

Another way might be to define a function which copies the original dictionary and only changes the desired values:

```
>>> def change_b(x):
...     new_x = x.copy()
...     new_x['b'] = x['b'] + 1
...     return new_x
...
>>> map(change_b, d)
[{'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'c': 7, 'b': 7}]
```

This, however, requires writing a separate function and loses the elegance of a lambda expression.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works (and is compatible with python2 and python3<sup>1</sup>):

```
>>> map(lambda x: dict(x, b=x['b']+1), d)
[{'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'c': 7, 'b': 7}]
```

With that said, I think that more often than not, `lambda` based solutions are *less* elegant than 
non-`lambda` counterparts...  The rational behind this statement is that I can immediately look at the non-`lambda` solution that you proposed and I know exactly what it does.  The `lambda` based solution that I just wrote would take a bit of thinking to parse and then more thinking to actually understand...

<sup><sup>1</sup>Though, `map` will give you an iterable object on python3.x that *isn't* a list...</sup>

Answer (score 3):

First, writing a function doesn't seem that inelegant to me in the first place.  That said, welcome to the brave new world of Python 3.5 and [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
>>> d = [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]
>>> d
[{'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 4}, {'b': 6, 'a': 5, 'c': 7}]
>>> [{**x, 'b': x['b']+1} for x in d]
[{'b': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 4}, {'b': 7, 'a': 5, 'c': 7}]
```

From how your `map` is behaving, it's clear you're using 2, but that's easy enough to fix. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop with an `update` call. Here is a hacky one-liner:

```
dcts = [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]
dcts = [d.update({'b': d['b']+1}) or d for d in dcts]
```

Edit: To preserve original dicts:

```
from copy import copy
dcts = [d.update({'b': d['b']+1}) or d for d in map(copy, dcts)]
```

Comment: This changes the original `d`.